# Unknown class RNEmailField in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have my app published on the app store, say version 1.2.

I'm developing version 1.3, if the current live application (taken from the app store, 1.2) is installed on my device and I build & run the project in Xcode on the very same device it crashes with:

```
2013-06-19 05:52:36.381 MyApp[12381:907] Unknown class RNEmailField in Interface Builder file.
2013-06-19 05:52:36.393 MyApp[12381:907] Unknown class RNAvatarImageView in Interface Builder file.
```

I removed every single instance of this plugin (installed via Pod) and it does not appear anywhere in the code now (I don't want it anymore).

If I uninstall the 1.2 live application from the phone, build & run 1.3 the application starts correctly. I made sure all the targets are ok, cleaned and cleaned build folder multiple times to no avail.

My fear is that once I release the upgrade the app will crash right at the start until a user uninstalls and reinstalls.

I did read all the other threads about this problem but nothing solves it beside uninstall the previous app version.

What should I do?

Comment: are this two classes(RNEmailField,RNAvatarImageView) 3rd party library....

Comment: yes definitely, installed via CocoaPods.

Comment: try adding both the .m files to your compile sources under build Phases

Comment: I removed these libraries from the project, should I add them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renamed MainStoryboard_iPhone to Main_iPhone and things got back to work.

Answer (score 0):

if you have removed this libraries..
 select your Email textfeild go to identity explorer and make class as UITextfeild ..
 same for Imageview.

Comment: I already did that. But I solved it, posting the answer in a bit.

Comment: Can't really answer for other 8 hours, anyway: So, after trying everything I just renamed the storyboard file.

From `MainStoryboard_iPhone` to `Main_iPhone` and reset the Main Storyboard option in Targets -> Deployment info.

Weird stuff.